# How to update a shared variable between functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, function, class

I am trying to update t1 in the execute function using the t1 value calculated in the runtime function.
They are in a class together.
Thanks for the help.

```
    def runtime(self, t1, t2):
        downtime = threading.Thread(target=Bot.downtime, args=(self, t2,))
        while t1 > -1:
            Mins, Secs = divmod(t1, 60)
            timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(Mins, Secs)
            print(timer, end="\r")
            time.sleep(1)
            t1 -= 1
            t1 = t1
            if t1 == -1:
                print("Finished")
                downtime.start()
                break

    def execute(self, termWeight, intervalWeight, pauseWeight, t1, t2):
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=Bot.runtime, args=(self, t1, t2,))
        thread1.start()
        while t1 != 0:
            driver.execute_script(Bot.script)
            time.sleep(intervalWeight)
            termWeight -= 1
            if termWeight == 0:
                time.sleep(pauseWeight)
                intervalWeight = random.uniform(.0025,.005)
                pauseWeight = random.uniform(.3,4)
                termWeight = random.randint(100,1000)
            if t1 == 0:
                break
```

Comment: Why is it not an instance attribute then?

Comment: @selcuk Can you explain? I am new to python.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't explain instance attributes in a comment box on Stack Overflow but you can find it in any introductory Python tutorial. In a nutshell you have access to the class instance (`self`) in all bound methods, so you can define an attribute (say, `t1`) and use it from either method using `self.t1`.